# node.js socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I try to catch a web site, but in this days have some problem.
show the socket hang up,

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:250:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:342:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is TCP/IP error: ECONNRESET (connection is reset by peer). You have connectivity problems. Example: a firewall is dropping your connection