# Containerized API socket hangs up

Tags: docker, rest, go, containers, postman

I just finished working on a Go REST API and I would like to move my code into a container. I already accomplished this, but I am unable to hit my endpoints through postman since the error: `Error: socket hang up` is thrown.

According to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234435/node-js-socket-hang-up), this could be caused by my firewall, after running `ufw status` I noticed my firewall is not up, so I am unsure what could be causing this error.

My app seem to be running correctly and I mapped the container with port 8080 in my local machine.

```
└─(19:14:04 on master ✭)──> docker ps                                                                                                                     ──(Tue,Feb02)─┘
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
b001f19e2957   go-library   "./library"   15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   cranky_kare
```

I also made sure my request are using this port.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/books/3
Error: socket hang up
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 190a5849-b859-4324-a65e-37a7b69b49fb
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same error

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that I was starting the server on `127.0.0.1` and the port mapping was not pointing to this interface. Starting it on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`) worked for me:

```
addr := fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0:%v", settings.Port)
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:         addr,
    Handler:      app.Router,
    IdleTimeout:  120 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
}
```

Comment: Hello! I don't seem to follow what the solution was, can you provide a bit more detailed explaination?

Comment: In go, I set the address to be `0.0.0.0:port` as opposed of `127.0.0.1:port`

Comment: Solution is not well explained.

Comment: @Marci-man added a snippet from my code